# How to make dropdown option selected against a variable in php

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown like the following.

```
 <select>
      <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
      <option value="Prof">Prof</option>      
    </select>
```

I am getting a value from data base in `$selected_value` variable. Based on this value I want to make one option from the above select to be `selected`.

Eg: If `$selected_value` = Mr, `<option value="Mr" selected>Mr</option>`

if   `$selected_value` = Dr, `<option value="Dr" selected>Dr</option>`

**update:**
now when i am inspecting element i am getting like below.but not selecting `Dr.`but it is orking in w3schools try editor.

```
<select>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Dr" selected="selected">Dr</option>
<option value="Prof">Prof</option>
</select>
```

**update 2**

see screen shot:
[image]

**update3**

now it works!   added name for `<select>`

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more ? Though I suggest you to open a new question.

Comment: Could you post your entire HTML for the page, and maybe, could you tell us which browser/browser version you're using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my solution so it fits yours I hope.

UPDATE:

```
    <select name="dropdownlist">
        <?
            $options = array("Mr", "Dr", "Prof");
            foreach($options as $option){
                if($_POST['dropdownlist'] == $option){
                    echo '<option selected="selected">' .$option. '</option>';
                }else{
                    echo '<option>' .$option. '</option>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: @NishamMahsin Hey, sorry for the delay. If your problem isn't solved yet please let me know so I can try to help you!

Comment: @NishamMahsin Try my updated code, I think your problem was that you should give a name to your <select> like in my example. Let me know if this helped!

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you problem

try this code

```
<select>
   <option value="Mr" <?=($selected_value=="Mr") ? "selected" : ""?>>Mr</option>
   <option value="Dr" <?=($selected_value=="Dr") ? "selected" : ""?>>Dr</option>
</select>
```

Comment: up 1 for beating me to it :P

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
<option value="Mr" <?php if($selected_value == 'Mr') echo 'selected' ?>>Mr</option>
      <option value="Dr" <?php if($selected_value == 'Dr') echo 'selected' ?>>Dr</option>
      <option value="Prof" <?php if($selected_value == 'Prof') echo 'selected' ?>>Prof</option>
```

Or you can use by using jquery

```
<script>
$('select option[value="<?php echo $selected_value ?>"]').attr('selected','true')
</script>
```

Comment: This is the most simplest way...just add to script and leave the select area alone....

Answer (score 2):

As per your current HTML use the code below:

```
<select name="your_select_name">
 <option <?php echo (($selected_value=="Mr")?"selected":"") ?> value="Mr">Mr</option>
 <option <?php echo (($selected_value=="Dr")?"selected":"") ?> value="Mr">Dr</option>
 <option <?php echo (($selected_value=="Prof")?"selected":"") ?> value="Mr">Prof</option>
</select>
```

If the value of this variable(`$selected_value`) returns **"Dr"** then 2nd option will be selected. And also give a name of your select tag.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHorvath, please check now

Answer (score 1):

If you also have an array of your options you could create the option tags by looping through each one of them. In that loop you then can check if the `$selected_value` matches `$option_value` like so:

```
<select>
<?php foreach($options as $option_value => $option_displayName) : ?>
<option 
  value="<?php echo $option_value; ?>" 
  <?php echo $option_value == $selected_value ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
<?php echo $option_displayName; ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want you'd have to build the select dynamically like the following example:

```
<?php 

$selects = array(
  array('name' => 'Mr', 'value' => 'Mr'),
  array('name' => 'Dr', 'value' => 'Dr'),
  array('name' => 'Prof', 'value' => 'Prof'),
);

$selected_option = 'Dr';

echo '<select>';
foreach($selects as $select) {
    if($select['value'] == $selected_option) {
        echo '<option value="'.$select['value'].'" selected>' .$select['name']. '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$select['value'].'">' .$select['name']. '</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';

?>
```

Which outputs:

```
<select>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Dr" selected>Dr</option>
<option value="Prof">Prof</option>
</select>
```

#### Example

Comment: @NishamMahsin How are you making this form? If it is static (you writing the html out) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows .

```
<select name="select_options">
  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
  <option value="Prof">Prof</option>      
</select>
```

After hit submit button. Then you will get value in `$_POST['select_options']`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you're doing. I can think of two straight ways to do this.

The first is ugly:
Insert in each option a php tag and check if value is selected:

```
<select>
  <option <?php if ($selected_value == 'Mr') echo 'selected'; ?> value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option <?php if ($selected_value == 'Dr') echo 'selected'; ?> value="Dr">Dr</option>
  <option <?php if ($selected_value == 'Prof') echo 'selected'; ?> value="Prof">Prof</option>      
</select>
```

Otherwise, I would personally write a little helper

```
function generateSelect(array $entries, $selected)
{
    $ret = '<select>'
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $ret .= '<option';
        if ($entry == $selected) {
            $ret .= ' selected';
        }
        $ret .= ' value="'.$entry.'"';
        $ret .= '>'.$entry.'</option'>;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

It is just an example and its functionality could be expanded. It SHOULD work, but I haven't tried it myself (wrote it quickly)

Answer (score 0):

You have mistaken syntax

```
<select>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Dr" selected="selected">Dr</option>
<option value="Prof">Prof</option>
</select>
```

this will work

```
<select>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Dr" selected>Dr</option>
<option value="Prof">Prof</option>
</select>
```